# Why does fopen succeed where CreateFile fails?

Tags: winapi

In my Win7 64bit system, I create many text files with my own program that uses:

```
hLogFile = CreateFile (LogFileSpec,GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,
                     CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS,NULL);
```

When one of these files is open (being displayed on the screen), I cannot open it again (file sharing violation) in another program using:

```
hSrcFile = CreateFile (SrcSpec,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,
                     OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
```

However, when one of these files is open (being displayed on the screen), I can open it again in another program using:

```
hFile = fopen(FileSpec,"rb");
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?  Why can't BOTH methods open the currently displayed file in read-share mode?

I really don't want to go
back to yesteryear and use the `fopen()` stuff from the C runtime library, but I
cannot find anything in the Win32 API that will accomplish the job. Any ideas?

Comment: fopen() uses a bad practice, replaced in C11 Annex K by fopen_s().  You'd need to add FILE_SHARE_WRITE to do with it does.  This typically only ever comes to a good end when this is a text file and the other process only ever appends to the file.  Beware of reading partially written lines.

Answer (score 1):

The first `CreateFile()` is creating the file for reading AND writing, and is sharing read-only access.

The second `CreateFile()` is opening the file for reading only (OK), but is sharing read-only access (sharing violation).

Since the file is opened for writing, and the second call does not include write sharing, the second call fails.

You need to add `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` to the second call:

```
hSrcFile = CreateFile (SrcSpec, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

Comment: In terms of implementation, the `SHARE_ACCESS` record for a file tracks how it has been opened for data access (not metadata), i.e. read (and execute), write (and append), or delete access. It counts the overall number of times a file was opened for any data access, and also the individual open and share counts for each access type. Thus requesting read access will fail if the file has been opened for data access more than read access was shared, and it also fails, as in the OP's case, if the file has been opened for write access and the current request doesn't share write access.

Comment: The program that creates the file does not WANT any other program
 to be able to write to the file while it is open.  Far as I know, no OS I've ever used would ever allow that anyway.  Please keep in mind that the fopen() C runtime function DOES DO exactly what I want. Also, adding FILE_SHARE_WRITE does not work anyway.  If nobody comes up with a CreateFile solution to this problem, I'll hafta just swallow my pride and drop back to the fopen() stuff.  But I really don't want to do that!

Comment: @user3648496 your second `CreateFile()` does not want other processes writing to the file, that is why it fails. Adding `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` does work, I use this *EXACT* setup in my own apps using `CreateFile()`, where one app writes to a log file (created for reading+writing w/ read sharing), and another app reads from the same log file while it is being written to (opened for reading w/ read+write sharing). It works fine on every system I've ever run it on. If it is not working for you, you are not using it correctly.

Comment: @user3648496, `fopen` calls `CreateFile` with read and write sharing. The 2nd File object has to share write access since the first File object has write access. That doesn't mean the 2nd File will be able to get write access; it cannot because the first File does not share it. Also, don't think of this in terms of programs. The error message for `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` is misleading (i.e. "...being used by another process"). The share access is checked whenever a File object is created that requests data access (read, write, delete) and is unrelated to any process.

Comment: "no OS I've ever used would ever allow that". Either you've never used Unix/Linux or never did much POSIX programming. These systems do not have the DOS/Windows concept of shared data access. Even explicit file locking in POSIX is usually advisory instead of mandatory.

Comment: Remy, everything you say is correct.  Adding FILE_SHARE_WRITE does
fix my problem.  I apologize for screwing up the test and reaching
the wrong conclusion the first time you told me.  Thanks for taking
the time to beat it into my head the second time. :-)  And eryksun
was right when he suggested that I had never tried Unix, Linux or
Posix.  I started with PDP-11s in 1972, where the operating system 
was <NONE> and the mass-storage device was paper tape (no lie).
It's easy to love Win32 if you've started with punched paper tape!